# Pyserial converting bytes to normal string

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am receiving a packet through a serial port but when I receive the packet it is of class bytes and looks like this:

```
b'>0011581158NNNNYNNN  +6\r'
```

How do I convert this to a normal string? When I try to take information from this string, it comes out as a decimal representation it appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert byte array to Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-byte-array-to-python-string)

Comment: @aruisdante alright that decode method didn't seem to work for me when I was working on a different part. However, do you know what the +6 part of my string stands for? I'm not very familiar with serial port communication.

Comment: I mean, it's a byte array. It could be literally anything. The fact that it happens to work out to the characters ``'+6\r'`` could be a total coincidence. You need to know the packet format for whatever is sending you serial data.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on the bytes object to convert it to a string, but that only works if the bytes object actually represents text:

```
>>> bs = b'>0011581158NNNNYNNN  +6\r'
>>> bs.decode('utf-8')
'>0011581158NNNNYNNN  +6\r'
```

To really parse the input, you need to know the format, and what it actually means. To do that, identify the device that is connected to the serial port (A scanner? A robot? A receiver of some kind?). And look up the protocol. In your case, it *may* be a text-based protocol, but you'll often find that bytes stand for digits, in which you'll probably want to have a look at the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).